# настроить Apache для yii2 starter kit

Tags: php

использую OpenServer на windows, установил yii2-starter-kit, но не могу настроить Apache в htaccess

```
# End the processing, if a rewrite already occurred
RewriteRule ^(frontend|admin|teacher|student)/web/ - [L]

# Handle the case of backend, skip ([S=1]) the following rule, if current matched
RewriteRule ^admin(/(.*))?$   backend/web/$2 [S=1]
RewriteRule ^teacher(/(.*))?$ teacher/web/$2 [S=1]
RewriteRule ^student(/(.*))?$ student/web/$2 [S=1]

# handle the case of frontend
RewriteRule .* frontend/web/$0
RewriteRule .* teacher/web/$0
RewriteRule .* admin/web/$0
```

RewriteRule .* student/web/$0

таким образом прописываю

```
<VirtualHost *:%httpport%>

    DocumentRoot    "%hostdir%"
    ServerName      "%host%"
    ServerAlias     "%host%" %aliases%
    ScriptAlias     /cgi-bin/ "%hostdir%/cgi-bin/"

 </VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:%httpport%>

    DocumentRoot    "%hostdir%/backend/web/"
    ServerName      "%host%"
    ServerAlias     "%host%"
    ScriptAlias     /cgi-bin/ "%hostdir%/cgi-bin/"

</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:%httpport%>

    DocumentRoot    "%hostdir%/student/web/"
    ServerName      "%host%"
    ServerAlias     "%host%"
    ScriptAlias     /cgi-bin/ "%hostdir%/cgi-bin/"

</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:%httpport%>

    DocumentRoot    "%hostdir%/teacher/web/"
    ServerName      "%host%"
    ServerAlias     "%host%"
    ScriptAlias     /cgi-bin/ "%hostdir%/cgi-bin/"

</VirtualHost>
```

так прописываю, но не работает, как правильно прописать хосты?

Comment: Что именно не работает?

Comment: An Error occurred while handling another error:
yii\base\InvalidRouteException: Unable to resolve the request: site/error in D:\myProgramm\OSPanel\domains\site.localhost\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php:128
Stack trace:
#0 D:\myProgramm\OSPanel\domains\site.localhost\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(528): yii\base\Controller->runAction('error', Array)
#1